# FTP response 421 received. Server closed connection

Tags: java, ftp, apache-commons, apache-commons-net

I am trying to connect to an FTP site using this code [access FTP using java](http://www.kodejava.org/examples/357.html)

but i got this exception:

```
org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPConnectionClosedException: FTP response 421 received.  Server closed connection.
```

So what is i am doing it wrong? i can access this FTP location with no problem using my browser

Anyone have an idea?

Thank you

Comment: For anyone who have this problem with commons-net, use ftp4j library instead, and it will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

Hard to say, try adding a protocol Listner (before the client.connect() to get some more info:

```
 client.addProtocolCommandListener(new PrintCommandListener(new PrintWriter(System.out), true));
```

Comment: used ftp4j library and it solved my probelm http://www.sauronsoftware.it/projects/ftp4j/index.php